# Stuck on dropdown.js

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

```
$(function(){
    // Show hide popover
    $(".dropdown").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
$(document).on("click", function(event){
    var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
    if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
        $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
    }            
});
```

This is my js for dropdown, and when I click on a few (I have multiple) it doesn't close the previous one and I need it to do so, otherwise it'll get flooded with dropdown menus.

I'm still learning js so I run into a few bumps here or there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea with this sort of thing is to listen for clicks and close your dropdown(s) if the click did not come **from the dropdown itself or any of its child elements**.

For this you can use `closest()`.

```
$(() => {
    $(".dropdown").on('click', () => {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    });
    $('body').on('click', event => {
        if (!$(event.target).closest('.dropdown').length)
            $('dropdown-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, I remember now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea is to close all dropdowns and then pop open the one clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").click(function(){
        $(".dropdown .dropdown-menu").slideUp();
        $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideDown("fast");
      }); 
});
```

Comment: True - except this won't close any open dropdown when the user clicks away to somewhere else on the page which, although the OP didn't explicitly ask for this, is almost certainly desired behaviour.